# Premise: I play poker at a table limited to 6 players plus a dealer. All players are competing ONLY with the dealer.

Tags: probability

Premise:  I play poker at a table limited to 6 players plus a dealer.  All players are competing ONLY with the dealer.

Question:  Are odds better for the player when there is only 1 player at the table, versus 2 thru 6 players at the table?

It is my thought that if I am playing alone against the dealer, and in need of specific card(s)to improve my hand, my odds are improved as there are more cards in the deck available to me that could otherwise be held by other players.

Comment: Whatever it is you're playing, it's not poker.

Comment: Your question makes no sense if the bank has any choice of action such as being able to fold seeing others' bets.  If not, then having other players will affect the result if you are playing draw poker or if you can see some of their personal cards though probably not if not.

Comment: A more likely model on this is blackjack http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack, where it generally *is* against the dealer alone.  Interestingly, while the number of players does not affect any individual player's chance of winning, the dealer will often win - or lose - against all players simultaneously (by getting blackjack, or by busting); per-hand dealer wins in blackjack are not subject to the central limit theorem.  This doesn't, I think, hold quite as true in poker, especially if you're forced to play.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're playing Texas Hold'em, the odds of you getting the two particular cards in your hand then 5 particular cards appearing on the table is not affected by other players, therefore your odds aren't changed.